# How to disable the need for making operations with sudo

Tags: sudo, files, directory, root, dropbox

I can read my Dropbox directory from Ubuntu OS. However, in order to delete/create/move file to this directory I must use "sudo". This means that I can do these operation only by shell.

Is there any option to tell Ubuntu to treat the Dropbox directory just like any other directory? meaning no need to use 'sudo' for the mentioned operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for this, unless the permissions of the Dropbox folder are incorrect.  Make sure that you are the owner of the directory.

On my machine, the Dropbox directory has permission 700 with myuser.myuser as the owner.  Obviously, I can move/copy files to it just fine.  This is with Dropbox v3.14.7

Comment: my permission was also 700, and I still couldn't write to Dropbox. I changed it to 777 and now writing is permitted.

Comment: Who owned the directory?  That may be why you need to make it 777 instead of 700.